# How do I pause postgrey?

Tags: centos, spf, postgrey

If I use `service stop postgrey`, then I get errors in my maillog

```
Mar 17 18:49:10 ip-172-31-15-65 postfix/smtpd[23543]: warning: problem talking to server postgrey/socket: No such file or directory
Mar 17 18:49:10 ip-172-31-15-65 postfix/smtpd[23543]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[192.163.199.86]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration problem; from=<jacqueline_ward-@goforgummies.com> to=<> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.goforgummies.com>
```

How do I pause postgrey to accept everything temporarily? I'm getting emails from AmazonSES which are violating RFC (I believe) by using random from addresses and random servers.

```
[root@kizbit ~]# cat /var/log/maillog | postgreyreport | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | grep amazon | head -n20
     12 0100015ad3a1bd19-3a06e9aa-d72c-4c2d-af61-0aa8f8172e9c-#@amazonses.com
     10 0100015ad7e29a84-f4bb8c77-ff56-476c-aefd-c07989ea672f-#@amazonses.com
      7 0100015acfbd9001-5216a5fc-ffd8-4c42-9d22-5f66b8462154-#@amazonses.com
```

postgrey 1.34

Comment: You'll need to edit your postfix configuration to stop using postgrey to check mail.

Comment: I found this worked too: `echo amazonses.com >> /etc/postfix/postgrey_whitelist_clients.local; service postgrey reload`

Comment: those are valid emails

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2049510/2774776

Comment: @JacobEvans The question isn't whether they are valid email addresses, it's whether they violate RFC by re-trying after a delay from a different email address and a different server. http://postgrey.schweikert.ch/ "When a request for delivery of a mail is received by Postfix via SMTP, the triplet CLIENT_IP / SENDER / RECIPIENT is built. If it is the first time that this triplet is seen, or if the triplet was first seen, less than 5 minutes ago, then the mail gets rejected with a temporary error. Hopefully spammers or viruses will not try again later, as it is however required per RFC."